# Is there a simple way to condense this code?

Tags: python-3.x

This is the snippet of code for a dinosaur hunting style game I am currently programming/testing. This is by far the most horribly inefficient part of the code and I was interested as as to whether there were many areas to properly condense. The stats generated by this are simply passed on into a class structure to create the actual creature. As the proposed stats of the creatures past trophy 3 will continue to rise (in a non-linear fashion) I see no simple mathematical way of condensing the code, though as I consider myself to be a rather inefficient Python programmer I was hoping this could be condensed with some help.

```
Trophy1 = ["Compsognathus", "Coelophysis", "Troodon"]
Trophy2 = ["Edmontosaurus", "Iguanadon", "Parasaurolophus"]
Trophy3 = ["Deinonychus", "Utahraptor", "Novaraptor"]
Trophy4 = ["Protoceratops", "Avimimmus", "Gallimumus"]
Trophy5 = ["Allosaurus", "Carnotaurus", "Baryonyx"]
Trophy6 = ["Stegosarus", "Arrhinoceratops", "Triceratops"]
Trophy7 = ["Ankylosaurus", "Minmi", "Euplocephalus"]
Trophy8 = ["Abelisaurus", "Albertosaurus", "Gorgosarus", "Megalosaurus"]
Trophy9 = ["Apatasaurus", "Brachiosaurus", "Brontosaurus"]
Trophy10 = ["Tyrannosaurus Rex","Giganotosaurus","Spinosaurus"]
Trophy11 = ["Indominous Rex"]
if Trophy == 1:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy1)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 1
elif Trophy == 2:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy2)
    EHealth = random.randint(100,250)
    EAttack = random.randint(30,75)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,15)
    Weight = random.randint(500,1000)
    Carnivore = 1
elif Trophy == 3:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy3)
    EHealth = random.randint(100,200)
    EAttack = random.randint(50,100)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(250,500)
    Carnivore = 2
elif Trophy == 4:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy4)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 1
elif Trophy == 5:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy5)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 2
elif Trophy == 6:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy6)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 1
elif Trophy == 7:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy7)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 1
elif Trophy == 8:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy8)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 2
elif Trophy == 9:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy9)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 1
elif Trophy == 10:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy10)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 3
elif Trophy == 11:
    Name = random.choice(Trophy11)
    EHealth = random.randint(50,100)
    EAttack = random.randint(20,50)
    Resistance = random.randint(5,10)
    Weight = random.randint(100,150)
    Carnivore = 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all those data into an array, then index it (don't forget to subtract one of `Trophy` to get the appropriate index). Or, you can create a class like `DinosaurDataDescriptor` and put that objects into an array.

Comment: Ah okay, I see, thank you. I'm assuming this is just because array indexing starts at 0, rather than 1?